# error MSB8020: Platform Toolset set to V140, but error says it can't find V110

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

When I right click the project and go to settings, I can clear see that the Platform Toolset is set to Visual Studio 2015 (v140). However, when I go to compile the project, the error says

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(54,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2012 (Platform Toolset = 'v110') cannot be found. To build using the v110 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2012 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".
```

I tried doing the recommendation, and "retarget solution," but that does nothing.

If I open the references .targets file, I see no references to V140. I tried changing all of the references from V110 (as an experiment) to V140, but when I went to recompile, it just changed them all back to V110 and generated the same error.

Any ideas on how to stop VS from targeting V110 when it says that it is targeting V140?

Comment: The obvious case is when your solution has multiple projects and you are just tinkering with the wrong one.  The non-obvious case requires you to document the question with the detailed MSBuild trace.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say that I am pretty sure it is happening on that project, because if I do a Project Only>Build Only I still get the error.

However, thanks for the MSBuld trace, TIL how to go into Diagnostic mode to take a closer look. I am reviewing that output now. Hopefully, that will give me the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Well, you were right, I was tinkering with the wrong project. It was referencing a dependent project that wasn't included in the solution, so I had never modified the toolset. I should know by now to always comb through the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with a project being referenced by my project that hadn't been included in the solution. Diagnostic output verbosity helped me find it.